# Should I use a tableView for this

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

So I'm currently working on a project at work and wanted to get some feedback on how I would accomplish this. One of the mobile developers suggested I use a dynamic tableView, but it sounded kind of complicated for what I needed to accomplish. I just created UIButtons and UILabels, but felt that was rather cheesy. What do you all think? See image below

[image]

Comment: you can use collectionview or tableview

Comment: Any of the above. There's not a right answer here; they're all fine. I've generally done this kind of work with a static table view in the storyboard, but if I had to do it today, I'd probably use a stack view. But really, any solution you're kind of comfortable with (including buttons and labels) would be totally fine here as long as you use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionview or UITableview but

When using UICollectionview, you don't need to set buttons with tags or other things by getting selected items values. You can simply get `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and in **UITableViewDelegate**:

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You get the selected row instead of the item, so for creating a grid or modified items, using UICollectionview is best. Here if you need rows only you can also use UITableview.